# void type not allowed here in servlet

Tags: java

This is my java class :

```
   public String year, title,detail;
public League(String year,String title,String detail)
{
    this.year=year;
    this.title=title;
    this.detail=detail;
}
public void getTitle()
{
    System.out.println(""+year+""+title+""+detail+"");
}
```

This is my servlet:

```
     protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {
    processRequest(request, response);
    //Creats the set of league
    leagueList=new LinkedList();
    leagueList.add(new League("2003","Spring","Soccer League(Spring`03)"));
    leagueList.add(new League("2003","Summer","Summer Soccer Fest"));
    leagueList.add(new League("2003","Fall","Fall Soccer League"));
    leagueList.add(new League("2004","Spring","Summer Soccer Fest"));
    leagueList.add(new League("2004","Summer","Soccer League(Spring`03)"));
    leagueList.add(new League("2004","Fall","Fall Soccer League"));
}
```

This is my processRequest() method

```
    out.println("<ul>");
        Iterator items=leagueList.iterator();
        while(items.hasNext()){
            out.println("<li>"+League.getTitle()+"</li>");
        }
        out.println("</ul>");
```

Error is: League.getTitle(); //void type not allowed

Answer (score 1):

The error is very descriptive. You're returning a `void` or, in other words, the `getTitle` method returns nothing. Java can't concatenate the result of void (nothing) to a `String`.

Change the method to become a proper getter:

```
public String getTitle() {
    return title;
}
```

Also, create proper getter methods for the other fields as well:

```
//year field should be an int rather than a String
public String getYear() {
    return year;
}

public String getDetail() {
    return detail;
}
```

Comment: i follow the same but now it is showing that "Non static method cannot be referenced from static context". when i declare member variables and member function as static nothing happen.

Comment: @mukeshvishwas why are you declaring these fields or methods `static`? That's not good. Please provide your exact piece of code and what you have in mind.

Comment: I calling getter method from here: out.println("<li>"+League.getTitle()+"</li>");  without static it is not permitting me to declare ie. League.getTitle(); please refer above code

Comment: Here is: out.println("<ul>");
            Iterator items=leagueList.iterator();
            while(items.hasNext()){
                out.println("<li>"+League.getYear()+"</li>");
                out.println("<li>"+League.getTitle()+"</li>");
            }
            out.println("</ul>");

Answer (score 1):

`getTitle()` returns nothing (`void`) and you're trying to add this to a String.

Use this:

```
public String getTitle()
{
    return year + title + detail;
}
```